# How can I to force JavaFX ComboBox dropdown list cells to be re-rendered?

Tags: java, javafx, combobox

I have a Java 8 editable ComboBox where the default item is bolded and the non-default items are unbolded by a CellFactory.
When the default is changed to another item, the only way I have found to get the new default bolded and the old default unbolded by the CellFactory is to delete and re-add both the old and new default items. This necessitates a fair bit of code to deal with a new item becoming current because the previous current item was removed and then setting the current item to the item we were modifying.

Is there a nice way to flag a cell as dirty and needing re-rendering so I don't have to remove and re-add 2 cells?

I have spent half a day googling but maybe I'm not asking the right questions.

I suppose the controlling code would be simpler if I just cleared all the combobox items and re-added them all, but that's not very efficient.

Edit: As requested, here is CellFactory:

```
            bookComboBox.setCellFactory(
        new Callback<ListView<String>, ListCell<String>>() {
            @Override public ListCell<String> call(ListView<String> param) {
                final ListCell<String> cell = new ListCell<String>() {
                    {
                        super.setPrefWidth(100);
                    }
                    @Override public void updateItem(String item,
                        boolean empty) {
                            super.updateItem(item, empty);
                            if (item != null) {
                                setText(item);
                                if (item.equals(Book.getDefaultBook())) {
                                    setFont(Font.font("System", FontWeight.BOLD, 14));
                                    System.out.println("bookComboBox.setCellFactory: set BOLD item=" + item);
                                }
                                else {
                                    setFont(Font.font("System", FontWeight.NORMAL, 14));
                                    System.out.println("bookComboBox.setCellFactory: set NORMAL item=" + item);
                                }
                            }
                            else {
                                setText(null);
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    return cell;
                }
            });
```

I'm not changing the values of the cells, just the font used when rendering.
I'm not using onEditCommit().
I use bookComboBox.setOnAction listener to react to combobox selection changes.
The setOnAction event also occurs when text is entered in the combobox and Action key (ENTER) is pressed or Combobox loses focus.

Comment: How is the CellFactory implemented? Presumably, all that's needed is to update the control(s) inside it...

Comment: Please show some code, or you using ```onEditCommit``` ? In principle, cells should get re-rendered automatically.

Comment: @jorn: The cells are only automatically rendered once. It seems you have to change the value in a cell or remove/add it again to get it re-rendered. All of these options cause unwanted ComboBox.setOnAction events to occur.

Comment: I see from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Cell.html that only the no of cells necessary to show the VisibleRowCount are rendered, so if the list is scrolled, then cells may be re-rendered, but this doesn't help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using a `ObservableValue<Boolean>` that tells you whether the item should be bold or not for each cell, you can create a binding that updates the font.

Example:

This uses each item as default for 1 sec before using the next as default.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    ComboBox<String> comboBox = new ComboBox<>(FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            "item 1",
            "item 2",
            "item 3",
            "item 4",
            "item 5"
    ));

    final Font BOLD_FONT = Font.font("System", FontWeight.BOLD, 14);
    final Font NORMAL_FONT = Font.font("System", FontWeight.NORMAL, 14);

    final StringProperty defaultValue = new SimpleStringProperty();
    comboBox.setCellFactory(lv -> new ListCell<String>() {

        {
            // use bold font if the item property contains the
            // same value as the defaultValue property
            fontProperty().bind(Bindings.when(itemProperty().isEqualTo(defaultValue))
                                        .then(BOLD_FONT)
                                        .otherwise(NORMAL_FONT));
        }

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            if (empty || item == null) {
                setText(null);
            } else {
                setText(item);
            }
        }

    });

    // change default every second
    PauseTransition animation = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(1));
    EventHandler<ActionEvent> eventHandler = new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        private Iterator<String> iterator = comboBox.getItems().iterator();

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            if (!iterator.hasNext()) {
                iterator = comboBox.getItems().iterator();
            }
            defaultValue.set(iterator.next());
            animation.play();
        }
    };

    animation.setOnFinished(eventHandler);

    eventHandler.handle(null);
    Scene scene = new Scene(comboBox);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: Hi Fabian, Thanks very much! The above code doesn't compile though. 2 missing symbol problems: Bindings.with and Duration.seconds. I don't need the Duration.seconds but it would be nice if you could fix it so this is a working example.

Comment: @ChrisGood: Both are part of the javaFX API. you need to import `javafx.beans.binding.Bindings` and `javafx.util.Duration`

Comment: Ah! I had let netbeans add the imports and it wrongly picked javax.script.Bindings and java.time.Duration. Live and learn. Works now - thanks again!